# Apache HTTPD Redirect with Condition

Tags: apache, redirect

I have to redirect anything **http://www.mycompany.com/old** to **http://www.mycompany.com/new**.

The problem is, i have to keep **http://www.mycompany.com/old/images/bg.jpg** . I currently use REDIRECT PERMANENT, which redirect everything to the new subdirectories.

How do i achieve that, keeping this http://www.mycompany.com/old/images/bg.jpg and redirect everything besides this ? 
Thanks for the prompt replies

Answer (score 0):

It is all in the order; redirect or alias that URL *first* and then do the remainder.

And specifically see the flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
L | last
```

which is to "Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules. Especially note caveats for per-directory and .htaccess context (see also the END flag). details ..."

So null rewrite on ^/images/bg.jpg  with a L will exempt just that entry.

If it is truly one URL you can also negate  with the ! and do first a RewriteCond !^/images/bg.jpg - and then do the new/old rewrite.

```
RewriteCond !^/images...etc
RewriteRule /old(.*) /new$1 R=...
```

or even

```
RewriteCond !^/images1...etc AND
RewriteCond !^/images2...etc AND
RewriteCond !^/images3...etc
RewriteRule /old(.*) /new$1 R=...
```

Dw.

Comment: can you explain the actual result. im kinda lost, and new to mod rewrite.

Comment: In that case - have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html and http://webdesign.about.com/od/mod_rewrite/qt/site_redirects.htm - that should help.